# Universal Image Loader Load bitmap from memory

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

Universal Image Loader provide many ways to load the image.

```
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video.mp4" // from SD card (video thumbnail)
"content://media/external/images/media/13" // from content provider
"content://media/external/video/media/13" // from content provider (video thumbnail)
"assets://image.png" // from assets
"drawable://" + R.drawable.img // from drawables (non-9patch images)
```

But all these way load image form file, I need a way to load from memory since my images was encrypted and stored in the assets folder, When I display this image, I need the following steps.

1. decrypt the image into bytes array.
2. Create bitmap from the bytes.
3. Load/display the image.

So it's something like this. Is that possible?

```
Bitmap bitmap = decrypt(encryptedImageFile);
imageLoader.displayImage(bitmap, imageView);
```

Currently, I am considering to save the bitmap to file and load the file, but this will take more time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below is what you are seeking if your images are stored in image folder in assets directory, then you can get the list of images

```
  private List<String> getImage(Context conetx) throws IOException { 
      AssetManager assetManager =conetx.getAssets();
      String[] files = assetManager.list("image");   
      List<String> it=Arrays.asList(files);
      return it; 
  }
```

As a note, instead of using assets dir, put the file into /res/raw and you can then access it using the following URI

```
android.resource://com.your.packagename/" + R.raw.<nameoffile>
```

Comment: No, I want to load image from memory. I know how to read file from assets folder, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand this. You must know, If you have read the source code of `universal-image-loader`, the order of loading a image into a `ImageView` after the image's url is provided, is: memory, SDCard(if set), internet. That means after you called, `ImageLoader.display(url, imageview);`, it will look for the `Bitmap` from `memory` **first**, if it doesn't exist, if will look for the file of the image from `SDCard` then, if the file exist, if will convert the file into a `Bitmap`, then load the `Bitmap` into the `ImageView` and store it in memory. But if the file doesn't exist, it will download the image file of the `url`, then store the file into the `SDCard` and convert the file into a `Bitmap` and load the `Bitmap` into memory. **Most importantly, I recommend you to read source codes of it, if you are confused with what I post above.**

So, it is unnecessary for you to load the `Bitmap` from memory, `ImageLoader` will do it for you.

Comment: I know this process, but I need to display the encrypted image, if I don't read it from the memory, I have on chance to decrypt it. a work around is decrypt the image then store it to SD card and then display it by UIL, but that takes much time and the performance is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Lets choose own scheme so our URIs will look like "stream://...".

Then implement ImageDownloader. We should catch URIs with our scheme and return image stream.

```
public class StreamImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {
    private static final String SCHEME_STREAM = "stream";
    private static final String STREAM_URI_PREFIX = SCHEME_STREAM + "://";

    public StreamImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        if (imageUri.startsWith(STREAM_URI_PREFIX)) {
            return (InputStream) extra;
        } else {
            return super.getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
        }
    }
}


DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .build();


ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .imageDownloader(new StreamImageDownloader(getApplicationContext()))
        .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);



    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes);
    String imageId = "stream://" + stream.hashCode();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .extraForDownloader(stream)
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageId, imageView, options);
```